# Swipeout Menu not working while using SWReveal Library

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

Toggle not working in swipeMenu...when using SWRevealViewController library.. ihave been following these tutorial

http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

Here is the project :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6dTvD1JbkgBUmJ3SmNYeFdvOHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what error u faced..

Comment: no error..just the menu doesnot show...

Comment: K give the some time , I fix this issue

Comment: i have been debugging and it doesnot call the MenuController class...which contains the swipeMenu view

Comment: in which view controller revel toggle does not work

Comment: in NewBooking viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i found the bug in your project the Left menu is not allocated,Try changing the Menu Controller and don't attach the segues for cell.Just Change the Menucontroller and try, it is working
For cell segues you can call programmatically in tableviewdidselectrowatindexpath

here is link i have modified your code

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0pjD3FrutBsV3JiTDZ6aVAyWkE/view?usp=sharing

For eg:

```
 UINavigationController *navController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pager"];

  [self.revealViewController setFrontViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

Comment: yes..the modified project by you works well...but why not mine..its same

Comment: not sure, but for time being you can work the way i did and use tableviewdidselectrowatindexpath instead of cell segues

Comment: Ok now check ,I just removed all the segues and added again for only two,other you can do .Hope this serve ur purpose.I updated the link

Comment: Thanks it works...but really i needed to know what was my error?

Comment: my bad..i am not able to do it for HIstory VC...can you show how to do it for me

Comment: its same way shown in  appcoda link ,sometimes the segues are not properly set.just remove the segue and repeat it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77871/discussion-between-copeme-and-muku).

Comment: sometime i like to smash my head myself...i was selecting the accessory segues..so was the error

Comment: @muku I understand there are issues with the segues and having to set them again... but this is getting annoying I re-added all the segues by deleting them then re-attaching and still the same issue (by re-attach we mean just ctrl+drag to the corresponding controller right?) Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try yhis

```
    var home = BrowseViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil)
    var left = LeftMenuViewController(nibName: "LeftMenuViewController", bundle: nil)
    var nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: home)

    var revel = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: left, frontViewController: nav1)
    revel.delegate = self

    revel.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal
    window?.rootViewController = revel
```

Don't forget to set the delegate.

**To toggle you can use**

```
self.revealViewController().revealToggleAnimated(true)
```

**and to push new ViewController**

```
var nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc!)
                self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(nav, animated: true)
```

Comment: i didnot get you ..what you are telling

Comment: You can programmatically add the SWRevealViewController by using above code

Comment: did you notice my error? does adding these lines solves my problem?

Comment: use this on swipe menu tap on cell

Comment: oh..ok...i will give it a try