# Running project doesnot show the menu after files copied to another project while using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

This is my second question on the same topic.
[Swipeout Menu not working while using SWReveal Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30236357/swipeout-menu-not-working-while-using-swreveal-library)

I didn't figure out the error but knew that when i copy the running project files(class files,storyboard) and paste to the new project.The running code doesnot run on new project while using **SWRevealViewController** library. Is ther anything i need to add....

P.S. Bridging header is created after i dragged the both .h and .m files of SWRevealViewController library

The problem on new project is..no error but the bar button not showing the menu

UPDATED: This is the action method to show the menu.. However if you want my project just go to the above link

```
 @IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

            // Uncomment to change the width of menu
            //self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 62
        }

    }
```

Comment: put some code of click event on button

Comment: ok i have updated it

Comment: had you check using breakpoint that `revealToggle:` called or not?

Comment: it calls....... and all thing happens except doesnot initialize menucontroller class

Answer (score 0):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0pjD3FrutBsV3JiTDZ6aVAyWkE/view?usp=sharing

Ok now check ,I just removed all the segues and added again for only two,other you can do .Hope this serve ur purpose.I updated the link